# Implementing iterator for custom array

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, iterable

I am about to create my own iterable generic Array implementation. I've created an interface called `Iterable<E>`, which will 'force' all its inheritors to implement all of its pure virtual methods. The interface has following prototypes:

**Iterable**

```
public:
virtual Iterable<E>& operator=(const Iterable<E>& iter) = 0;
virtual bool operator==(const Iterable<E>& iter) const = 0;
virtual bool operator!=(const Iterable<E>& iter) const = 0;
virtual Iterable<E>& operator++() = 0;
virtual E& operator*() = 0;
```

In my `Array<E>` I've created following methods:

```
Iterable<E> begin();
Iterable<E> end();
```

Class `Array<E>` has annonymous nested implementation of `Iterable<E>`, which looks following:

**ArrayIterator**

```
class ArrayIterator : public Iterable<E> {
public:
    ArrayIterator(Array<E>* array, const int index) : _array(array), _index(index) {};

    ArrayIterator& operator=(const ArrayIterator& iter) override { _index = iter._index; return *this; }
    bool operator==(const ArrayIterator& iter) const override { return _index == iter._index; }
    bool operator!=(const ArrayIterator& iter) const override { return _index != iter._index; }
    ArrayIterator& operator++() override { _index++; return *this; }
    E& operator*() override { return _array[_index]; }
private:
    Array<E>* _array;
    int _index;
};
```

Then I returned `ArrayIterator` instances in both `begin()` and `end()` methods as:

```
  Iterable<E> Array<E>::begin() {
     return ArrayIterator(this, 0);
  }

  Iterable<E> Array<E>::end() {
     return ArrayIterator(this, this->length()); //length() returns array size
  }
```

Everything compiles just fine, but when I attempt to use for each, i'll throw an compile-time error:
**'Iterable cannon instantiable abstract class'**
in following example:

```
int main() {
   Array<int> array{1, 2, 3, 4};
   for(int i : array) {  //<- error points to this line

    }
}
```

As `Iterable` I've returned `ArrayIterator` which is its implementation, shouldn't it work through polymorphism?

Comment: There is no reason to make `Iterable`'s constructor private.  It has pure virtual functions and you cannot instantiate an object that has pure virtual functions.

Comment: I see no need for run-time polymorphism here.

Comment: `begin()` for const instance shouldn't return a non-const iterator.

Comment: Thanks to all for response. @SergeyA - I dont think is good idea to return ArrayIterator, it is Array's private class, or is there a reason?. liliscent - Thanks for pointing out, didnt even noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `begin` and `end` functions both return an `Iterable<E>`, not an `ArrayIterator`.  The `ArrayIterator` you create to return is *sliced* and only the base part of the created object is returned.

Since this requires creation of an abstract class, you get a compilation error.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How 'sliced' ? Any way to keep the ArrayIterator within the class?

Comment: It can't even be sliced, because `Iterable<E>` is abstract. Attempts to use this just won't compile, as the OP found.